# Unexpected short circuit evaluation when used more than one logical operators in C

Tags: c, logical-operators

In a C program:
`1 || 0 && 0` results in `1`. I thought this behavior as the OR operator has short-circuited rest of the right side (`0 && 0`) because of `1` on the left side.
But
`0 && 0 || 1` also results in `1`. I am confused why `0` on the left side of AND operator has not short circuited `0 || 1` and the answer is not `0`.
Please guide me!

Comment: `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`, so both expressions are logically equivalent.

Comment: See [Should I use parentheses in logical statements even where not necessary?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/201175/should-i-use-parentheses-in-logical-statements-even-where-not-necessary). TLDR; yes.

Comment: Careful of your terminology.   Frequently, `short circuit` means to avoid the evaluation of, so `1 || (c=getchar()) != EOF` would not evaluate the getchar() expression, and no character would be consumed; whereas `0 || (c=getchar()) != EOF` would always invoke the getchar().  The former, where the evaluation is avoided is commonly referred to as `short circuiting`.  Some of the precedence based expressions you cite are not.

Comment: Mujahid Ali, "But 0 && 0 || 1 also results in 1" is same as "But (0 && 0) || 1 also results in 1", so the first `0` did short-circuit to `(0 && anything) || 1` which is then `0 || 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

The logical AND operator has higher precedence than the logical OR operator ||.  So this:

```
1 || 0 && 0
```

Parses as:

```
1 || (0 && 0)
```

And this:

```
0 && 0 || 1
```

Parses as:

```
(0 && 0) || 1
```

So in the latter case, first `0 && 0` is evaluated.  This results in the value 0, so now you have `0 || 1`.  The left side of the OR is false so this causes the right side to be evaluated, causing the `||` operator to result in 1.

Comment: Got it...Thanks

Comment: If you like his answer, please mark it as accepted. (And it is a good answer!)

Comment: @TopologicalSort: When posting a comment to a post, only the author of the post will be notified of your comment. If you want someone else to additionally be notified, then you must use `@` and write their name, as I have done in this comment. Press the "Help" button while writing a comment for further information.